# How to solve conversion error in jmeter (cli)

Tags: xml, jmeter, load-testing

I would like to do some tests with jmeter. When I launch jmeter it says

> Don't use GUI mode for load testing !, only for Test creation and Test
> debugging.

So I tried to launch the test in no gui mode but I always have the same error ([See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHkyU.png)).

Here is the XML code of the file "cli-test.xml" (only do a simple GET request to google) that I did with the jmeter gui mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.4.1">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP Request" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">google.com</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">80</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
            <objProp>
              <name>saveConfig</name>
              <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                <time>true</time>
                <latency>true</latency>
                <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                <success>true</success>
                <label>true</label>
                <code>true</code>
                <message>true</message>
                <threadName>true</threadName>
                <dataType>true</dataType>
                <encoding>false</encoding>
                <assertions>true</assertions>
                <subresults>true</subresults>
                <responseData>false</responseData>
                <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                <xml>false</xml>
                <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
                <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                <bytes>true</bytes>
                <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
                <url>true</url>
                <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
                <idleTime>true</idleTime>
                <connectTime>true</connectTime>
              </value>
            </objProp>
            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          </ResultCollector>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Someone know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your test as:

```
./jmeter -n -t cli-test.jmx -l cli-result.jtl
```

this `-l` key tells JMeter to store the results in the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlTestLog), this file can later on be opened with a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) or you can [generate a HTML reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) from it

as your command is executing the JMeter which is on your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and most probably it's kind of outdated version which is not compatible with the [jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) format used in the latest JMeter 5.4.1

you can run `jmeter --version` command just for fun and see what you have installed, you might want to perform the upgrade in order to avoid such situations in the future.

More information: [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't have the error anymore. So just to be sure, it was because I didn't add `-l cli-result.jtl` ?

When I type `jmeter --version` I have _Version 2.13.20180731_ as result.

Comment: it was because in your case `jmeter` executes [JMeter 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/four-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213) which is good but 6 years old and `./jmeter` executes JMeter from the current folder which is probably [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) and newer test plans cannot be run using older JMeter versions